# Merge List of KeyValue Pairs

Tags: c#, linq, merge

I have a `List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>`, so the data looks something like:

```
user1, [trigger1,trigger2,trigger3]
user2, [trigger1,trigger4]
user3, [trigger2,trigger3,trigger4]
user1, [trigger0,trigger4]
```

I would like to make this a `Dictionary<string,List<string>>`, but directly this fails because there would be duplicate keys. Is there a way to merge the contents of the attached Values on the fly (meaning if there is user1 twice as keys, combine the two associated `Lists<>`) in LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group KVPs on `Key`, and use `SelectMany` to "flatten" the lists. If you do not want duplicates, use `Distinct()` to remove them:

```
var res = list
    .GroupBy(p => p.Key)
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key
    ,   g => g.SelectMany(p => p.Value).Distinct().ToList()
    );  //                              ^^^^^^^^^^
        // Remove Distinct() if you would like to keep all items
```

Comment: Looks good, except I don't need list1.Concat(list2) since I only have 1 list.

Comment: @FailedUnitTest I thought your KVPs were coming from different sources. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A `GroupBy` will do most of the work, combined with making a list of all the grouped items and you are done. The result of the `GroupBy` contains an enumerable of  lists, so we have to select all string items using `SelectMany` and construct a list out of that.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> d = l.GroupBy(k => k.Key)
                                      .ToDictionary( k => k.Key
                                                   , k => k.SelectMany(s => s.Value).ToList()
                                                   );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this through a series of chained LINQ queries in the following order :

- **`GroupBy()`** - This will create groups of each of your individual users to avoid issues when creating your dictionary (namely duplicate keys).
- **`ToDictionary()`** - This method will work to bind a given set of data using a key and a value, since you already have your keys (via the earlier call), you just need to get your values from each group.
- **`SelectMany()`** - This will select all of the individual values from your earlier groups, essentially merging all of the items from each set of users into a single collection.
- **`Distinct()`** - This will be applied on the list of strings generated in the previous step to remove any duplicates. If you want to allow duplicates, simply remove this step.

Implementing this would look something like the following snippet of code :

```
// Group the collections by user and then select the keys based on those users
var dictionary = list.GroupBy(l => l.Key)
                     .ToDictionary(
                            x => x.Key, 
                            x => x.SelectMany(l => l.Value)
                                  .Distinct()
                                  .ToList()
                     );
```

**Example**

```
// Example of your existing data
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>>(){
        new KeyValuePair<string,List<string>>("User 1", new List<string>(){ "trigger1" ,"trigger2", "trigger3" }),
        new KeyValuePair<string,List<string>>("User 2", new List<string>(){ "trigger1" ,"trigger2" }),
        new KeyValuePair<string,List<string>>("User 3", new List<string>(){ "trigger2" ,"trigger3", "trigger4" }),
        new KeyValuePair<string,List<string>>("User 1", new List<string>(){ "trigger0" ,"trigger4" }),
};

// Group the collections by user and then select the keys based on those users
var dictionary = list.GroupBy(l => l.Key)
                     .ToDictionary(
                            x => x.Key, 
                            x => x.SelectMany(l => l.Value)
                                  .Distinct()
                                  .ToList()
                     );

// Output each key with it's associated values
foreach(var key in dictionary.Keys)
{
        Console.WriteLine("Key: " + key + ", Values: " + String.Join(",",dictionary[key].ToArray()));
} 

// Example output 
// Key: User 1, Values: trigger1,trigger2,trigger3,trigger0,trigger4
// Key: User 2, Values: trigger1,trigger2
// Key: User 3, Values: trigger2,trigger3,trigger4
```

You can [see an interactive version of this here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a5qxwA).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>> myList = new List<KeyValuePair<string,List<string>>>() {
                 new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>("user1", new List<string> { "trigger1","trigger2","trigger3"}),
                 new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>("user2", new List<string> { "trigger1","trigger4"}),
                 new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>("user3", new List<string> { "trigger2","trigger3","trigger4"}),
                 new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>("user1", new List<string> { "trigger0","trigger4"})
            };

            Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = myList
                .GroupBy(x => x.Key, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Select(z => z.Value).SelectMany(a => a).ToList());

        }
    }
}
```